# MSCOMCTL.OCX Blues

Tags: com, vb6, registry, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

**MSCOMCTL blues**

Excuse me for the long post but I am trying to give all the related information.

I am moving a VB6 application from Windows server 2008 R2 to Windows server 2012 R2 running on vm.
This is a totally manual process.

I opened the vbp file with text editor and saved the dependencies in a text file.

I search the registry on the 2008 server for each of the dlls and ocx to find their location on the file system. Then, Copied all of them to the 2012 server and start registering each and everyone using regsvr32 in SysWoW64 folder.

I had quite a few issues with some of the dlls (third party and my own) but was able to figure and resolve.

The exe in 2012 was finally able to load BUT:

The date component we use (Infragistics PVDateEdit9.ocx) on a form could not show the calendar when pressing on the little arrow.
I then remembered from past installs that it had to do with MSCOMCTL.OCX which probably PVDateEdit9 is calling to drop the calendar.

I searched the 2012 registry and did not find a reference to it. I copied the one that was installed on server 2008 and registered it with SysWoW64 regsvr32. This did not help.

After spending some time on it, I decided to export all the registry keys for TypeLib key {831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1} from both servers and compared it. I found that the 2008 registry has only one more entry as follows which the 2012 does not have under each of the nodes (there are actually 5 nodes for this ocx):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\TypeLib\{831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}**\2.0**]
"PrimaryInteropAssemblyName"="mscomctl, Version=10.0.4504.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
```

The rest of the keys with version 2.2 were identical. Like

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\TypeLib\{831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}**\2.2**\0\win32]
@="C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\MSCOMCTL.OCX"
```

I believe that adding these PrimaryInteropAssemblyName keys to the 2012 can resolve the issue.

Before I try this, I have these questions:

First question - does anyone know what is the purpose of the "PrimaryInteropAssemblyName" key and how it came about in the 2008?

Second - did anyone have a similar problem?

Third - By adding these missing entries to the 2012 - can I cause a serious damage to the registry?

Thanks

Moshe

Comment: No, PIAs are an implementation detail for .NET.  Nothing whatsoever to do with vb6.  Yes, there is potential damage, it may well confuse the stuffing out of future .NET installers/programs that need the actual file to be present as well.

Comment: Since registering MSCOMCTL on the target VM didn't solve the problem you may have to look into additional missing dependencies. Dependencies of depdendencies... etc.

Comment: Hans - yes, I tried and did not help.

Comment: UuDdLrLrSs: This is an old ocx and no support is available. Is there a way to find what other dependencies an ocx might have? Thanks

Comment: The below answer seems to resolve the issue. Nonetheless I like to mention that MSCOMCTL.OCX itself has other dependencies, notably ComCat.dll (COM DLL) and comctl32.dll (native DLL).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever gets here with a similar issue with the very very old PVDate9.ocx not dropping the calendar, here is the resolution I found for my issue

It needs another ocx from the infragistics to be registered - PVCalendar9.OCX. It does not show anywhere that it depends on it. I search the .dep file in the original CAB of Ingragistics and it is not there. Once I registered the PVCalendar9.ocx it worked. IT IS NOTHING TODO with MSCOMCTL.OCX - I probably saw it somewhere on the internet. It does not need it.

How was I able to figure it out

I created a very simple exe with one form and only a PVDate control. I ran the exe on the computer where it was working (server 2008). I then used procexp (Procedure explore) and looked on the dlls that it loaded, and there it was, the PVCalendar9.OCX

Problem solved.

It is really time to start migrating these old old apps to new technology. :-)